# How to copy database to another server onto a specific disk in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

Help me please, and excuse me for my English.

I need to translate a database from a server to other, but in a specific disk (disk H:) - how to do this?

I have already done backup, but I have no to copied the database on the disk H:

**INFORMATION**

- OS: Windows 10
- Server OS: Windows Server 2016
- DB: Microsoft SQL Server 2014

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you have a good backup then just restore the backup. you can choose the drive when you do the restore.

Comment: When you restore a database either using `restore database` or in the SSMS GUI you can select the physical location of each file.

Comment: Try reading the `restore database` documentation, it even has an example of [Restoring a database and moving files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql#restoring_db_n_move_files)

Answer (score 0):

1- Take backup from source server using Restore option and restore to destination server using Restore Database option.

2- Right Click on Database select on -> Generate script
Choose Option - All Tables/Objects
Click on Advance from set scripting option
Make sure you have selected Schema & Data in Types of Data To Script

Select other options also as per your need.

Then Execute this generated script on destination server
change path accordingly as per your need.